# Is there support for SSL/HTTPS and certificates on Iron Foundry?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I've found a few articles about how to enable HTTPS on Cloud Foundry [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-collaboration/vcap/wiki). However these posts are quite old and the main problem is that I must decrypt HTTPS traffic before router (then re encrypt it) and before DEA with the help of nginx. That is not a very good solution because I need to explain why critical information travels unencrypted inside our system to the customer, and in general it seems unnecessary (maybe only to enable sticky session support, but currently I do not need this). The best solution will be to terminate HTTPS only on DEA itself, i.e. in IIS Hosted Web Core (which, I suppose, supports HTTPS). So, could you please tell me if it is possible (if it is, detailed description of how to do it is appreciated), or provide me another (newer) HTTPS solution which will be not so difficult to explain to the customer?